# SQL syntax error in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

Im trying to run this query

```
select customerID, sum(OrderID)
from employee_T
where 2 < select(sum(OrderID) from employee_T)
group by customerID;
```

I want to list the customer id and the total number of orders placed for every customer that has more than 2 orders.

I get the syntax error on this line

```
where 2 < select(sum(OrderID) from employee_T)
```

is it because of the 2?s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ms-access syntax, but this is how you would do that in regular sql:

```
select customerID, count(OrderID)
from employee_T
group by customerID
having count(orderID) > 2
```

Comment: `having` allows the use of aggregate functions like `count`, because it is applied after the grouping. `where` filters the rows before they are grouped, `having` filters them afterwards.